# How to represent page dots/breadcrumbs/page indicator in Watch Interface Builder?

Tags: swift, xcode, interface-builder, watchkit

Interface Builder shows the apple watch screen the way it will look without page dots at the bottom. Is there any way to add page dots to IB or any common practices for designing to spec in spite of this limitation? When I make a watch screen that is not vertically-scrollable the page dots cut off the bottom of the page or shift the whole screen up.

This is what it looks like in IB (as you can see there are no page dots)

[image: What it looks like in IB]

Edit: This is what it looks like after adding next page segue as was suggested.

[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what it looks like in Interface Builder?

Comment: Sure if it will help.

Answer (score 1):

To create a [a page-based interface](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/watchos/app-architecture/navigation/),

> You configure a page-based interface in your app’s storyboard by
>   creating a next-page segue from one interface controller to the next.
>
> 1. In your
>      storyboard, add interface controllers for each of the pages in your
>      interface.
> 2. Control-click your app’s main interface controller, and
>      drag the segue line to another interface controller scene.
> 3. The second
>      interface controller should highlight, indicating that a segue is
>      possible.
> 4. Release the mouse button. Select “next page” from the
>      relationship segue panel.
> 5. Using the same technique, create segues from each interface controller to the next. The order in which you create your segues defines the order of the pages in your interface.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/InterfaceStyles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH12-SW3

Comment: Yeah, I've tried this. I have a page-based interface in watch already, but unfortunately even when it is page-based interface builder does not show the page dots. I will edit my question and show you the image when I try.

Comment: Hmm, I’ll try to reproduce it when I’m on my Mac. What happens if you turn off Dark Mode in Mojave or the dark Xcode theme?

Comment: Nothing. Well I mean everything is extremely bright but otherwise no change.

Comment: The page dots show up on an actual device btw, I just want them to show in IB.

Comment: Same happens for me. I just filed a suggestion in Bug Reporter (#46951177) that page-based navigation should include the dots at design time. If you file it yourself too as a duplicate it will move up their priority list.